# Append data in sqlite3 c++

Tags: sqlite

i have a table in sqlite like:

e.g

Columns

|a |b |c |d |e |

|5 |6 |4 |3 |6 |

columns a - e holds an integer

now i need to add number to some columns

for example add 3 to column 'c'  and now c will hold 7.

how can i do it?

Comment: Shay, it sounds like you're just looking for a SQL Update statement? Have you looked at that? Or is the problem something else?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: thanks guys Krister Andersson gave me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be done with a simple `update` query like this:

```
UPDATE <table> SET c = c + 1;
```